# Does BingMap has limit in terms of request same like Google Map API?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

Currently I am using BingMap to get and set address. But I was reading about Google Map API.

According to it, user can send 1000 request per 24 hours. 150,000 request for 24 hours with credit card identification.

I have tried to find such limit in Bing Map, but didn't get.

Is there any limit for particular BingMapKey same like GoogleMap?

Please guide me else this will create issue if number of request get increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic accounts can make a maximum of 5 queries per second and a total of 125,000 transactions a year for free.

Enterprise accounts (licensed/paid) can make 50 queries per second an purchase higher queries per seconds if their account needs it. The transaction limits are based on the volume of transactions they purchased.